# Drawing & Changing an Image within a JPanel (from another class)

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, jpanel

So yeah, I'm trying to write a rock paper scissors program with images, but I'm having trouble at putting in the pictures. There seems to only be a small white square on the JPanel.

Here's the code for my Main Class:

```
public class Practice extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

// Images
final ImageIcon rockPic = new ImageIcon("D:\\JOVO\\RPS\\src\\rock.png");
final ImageIcon paperPic = new ImageIcon("D:\\JOVO\\RPS\\src\\paper.png");

// variables
String results = null;
Image pic = null;

//Image Panel
ImagePanel youPic = new ImagePanel();

public Practice() {

    // FRAME
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("RPS");
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // SUPER JPANEL
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    frame.add(this);

    // JPANELS - RPS title, JButton, PICTURES
    JPanel rpsTitle = new JPanel();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;
    rpsTitle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(rpsTitle, c);

    JPanel jbuts = new JPanel();
    c.gridy = 3;
    jbuts.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(jbuts, c);

    // ImagePanels
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.gridx = 0;
    add(youPic,c);

    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridx = 1;

    // JBUTTONS
    JButton rock = new JButton("  Rock  ");
    JButton paper = new JButton("  Paper  ");
    JButton scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
    jbuts.add(rock, BorderLayout.WEST);
    jbuts.add(paper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    jbuts.add(scissors, BorderLayout.EAST);
    paper.addActionListener(this);

    JButton resultB = new JButton("RES");
    c.gridy = 2;
    c.weighty = 10;
    add(resultB, c);
    c.weighty = 0;

    // FONTS
    Font rps = new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 28);
    Font labels = new Font(null, Font.ITALIC, 18);

    // JLABELS
    JLabel rpsTit = new JLabel("Rock, Paper, Scissors");
    rpsTit.setFont(rps);
    rpsTitle.add(rpsTit);

    JLabel you = new JLabel("You: ");
    you.setFont(labels);
    JLabel com = new JLabel("Com: ");
    com.setFont(labels);

    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridx = 0;
    add(you, c);

    c.gridx = 2;
    add(com, c);

    // PICTURES
    // comPic.setPic(rockPic);
    // youPic.setPic(pic);

}

public String test(String name) {
    // test the game

    return results;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // main stuffs
    Practice prac = new Practice();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Works");
    ImageIcon pic = null;
    pic = paperPic;
    youPic.setPic(pic);

    }
}
```

And my other class:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

Image pic = null;

public ImagePanel() {
    repaint();
}

public void setPic(ImageIcon pic) {
    // set picture for painting
    this.pic = pic.getImage();
    System.out.println("Set Pic");
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // paint
    super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("Painting");
    g.drawImage(pic, 0, 0, this);
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The preferred size of the `ImagePanel` is (0, 0) - you can override `getPreferredSize()` to return something sensible. I'd consider using a `JLabel` instead though, it does all the work needed.

Comment: JLabel and setIcon? Never thought of that, btw thanks! :)

Comment: You're welcome. JLabel is for images and label text, but the usefulness for displaying images alone is easily missed due to the name of the component. Easy to remember once you know it, though.